# Correct semantics to Make Modal Overlay disappear on click of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

I'm working on a modal and I want to make the modal overlay disappear when the background is clicked.

```js
function dismissModal() {
  document.getElementById("modal").classList.remove("modal-overlay");
}
```

```css
.modal-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 20em;
  width: 20em;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="modal" class="modal-overlay" onclick="dismissModal()">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h1>Example Code</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

It's not great for semantics to make a div or a section with an onClick property, but I don't want to wrap my entire modal section in a button or an anchor tag.

What do people typically do to avoid onClick in a div or section class in use cases like this?

Comment: I'm doing the actual work in react, so don't want to avoid DOM manipulation

Answer (score 0):

```
element.addEventListener(‘click’, event => /* Do stuff, hide modal */ )
```

With React/JSX:

```
const handler = event => /* Do stuff, hide modal */
const buttonComponent = <button onClick={handler} />
```

Comment: I'm doing the actual work in react, so don't want to avoid DOM manipulation

Comment: Well you definitely should have mentioned that up front. Are you using JSX?

Comment: Yes, I'm using jsx. Didn't include it because I thought issue is still relevant in simple example

Comment: Most major frameworks handle all dom manipulation for you, so they have their own unique APIs for things like event listeners.

Comment: This is a button that's calling a handler on click. In this scenario are you wrapping the entire app in a button?

Comment: No. Why would I do that? You should post your React code in your question or it’s going to be impossible to help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below snippet helps.

```js
function dismissModal() {
  document.getElementById("modal").classList.toggle("modal-overlay");
    document.getElementById("modal").classList.toggle("modal-hidden");
}
```

```css
.modal-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 20em;
  width: 20em;
  margin: auto;
}
.modal-hidden{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<section id="modal" class="modal-overlay" onclick="dismissModal()">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h1>Example Code</h1>
  </div>
</section>
<button onclick="dismissModal()">Show Modal</button>
```